# How to pull basic information from a YouTuber using the YouTube API in Python

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I installed the Google API Library, but I am having trouble figuring out the exact syntax to make any sort of API calls in Python. All I want to do is get a YouTubers total number of views, total number of posts, and total number of subscribers. I've spent hours trying to figure it out on their API documentation but I have had zero luck. Can anyone help me with the exact function I should be using and what I want to import in python before making these function calls? Thanks in advance!

```
import httplib2
import urllib2
from oauth2client.contrib import gce
credentials = gce.AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
data = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=massappeal").read()
print(data)
```

I keep getting a 403 error so maybe my authentication isn't correct? Also, is there a cleaner way to make the call other than with a URL?

UPDATE: all i was missing was the argument "key=YOUR_API_KEY" so my final code was:

```
import urllib2
from oauth2client.contrib import gce
data = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key=[YOUR API KEY HERE]&part=statistics&forUsername=%s" % handle).read()
print(data)
```

Comment: Hi,  and welcome to the forum. You should provide your own attempt here first and we can help if it does not work. We do not do your programming for you. There are plenty of examples of working code for example on youtube api documentation pages. You can start for example here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: hi @Hannu I updated my post. it's hard to post code when you dont know where to start...

Comment: You can start for example here. This is a working code snippet that queries some data about videos. The documentation pages are very, very good.  They also allow you to use a web form to make queries to see how the results look like. At least I found it very useful. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#set_and_retrieve_localized_video_metadata

Comment: @Hannu not sure how that fixes my 403 error but thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do you store your API access credentials and the client secret?

Comment: @Hannu i dont... how do i do that and how do i pass them before making my urllib2 call?